# Iterating through set with ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on some of code that try work with a set with ForEach, it is kind of working, the issue is here that with updating first character of new value it will end updating and does not let to finish the updating process. I want improve the updating logic without using `@FocusState` for TextField.

**My goal is that my codes waits for user to import all new character or the codes understands that the TextField is under editing und user did not press return key on keyboard.**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var set: Set<String> = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        SetforForEachWithBinding(set: $set)
        
    }
}

struct SetforForEachWithBinding: View {
    
    @Binding var set: Set<String>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(set.sorted(by: <), id: \.self) { element in
                
                TextField("Enter value here...", text: Binding(
                    get: { return element },
                    set: { newValue in
                        
                        if set.contains(element) {
                            set.remove(element)
                            set.insert(newValue)
                        }
                        
                    }
                ))
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `Set`? It is unordered container, so all behaves as expected. Just use another container.

Comment: Set is faster Array to searching for items, also it is for testing and learning.

Comment: @swiftPunk Why not use `OrderedSet` from the `OrderedCollections` Apple package?

Comment: @George: thanks, that needs to import, maybe I would use it at end, but I strongly believe we can solve this issue without it.

Comment: @swiftPunk Yeah, it would just make it easier. Anyways, using `set.first(where:)` is defeating the point in using `Set`, you probably are looking for `set.contains(_:)`

Comment: Oh! Yes exactly I felt about it but I missed that point! Thanks I will update my question. @George

Comment: If I remember well, `OrderedDictionary`from `Collections` packages doesn't yet fully conform to `RangeRepleaceableCollection` (the requirement for the collection used by SwiftUI's `ForEach` ). Just convert the set on the fly into an `Array` when using its elements in the `ForEach`: `ForEach(Array(set).sorted(by: <), id: \.self) { … }`

Comment: @valeCocoa: I already have working more advanced code that you said before asking the question, trying to use just set without help of array in between, also it makes no change in current question.

Comment: @swiftPunk you simply can't because `Set` doesn't conform of `RandomAccessCollection` (that is the requirement of `ForEach.Data` parameter, I've written `RangeReplaceableCollection` earlier which was a mistake). That is so cause `Set` uses an `Index` type which cannot provide O(1) complexity for offsetting its values (internally it uses *buckets* to store its elements).

Comment: @swiftPunk having given the elements you are using conform to `Comparable`, I can provide you with this data structure which keeps its elements sorted and conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`, but it's not modelled as a set, rather as associative array (dictionary): https://github.com/vale-cocoa/LLRBTree
Not that I'm somewhat cheating with the`Collection` conformance: it doesn't purely has a O(1) complexity for accessing its elements via subscript, but it's nearly close to that.

Comment: @valeCocoa: thanks for your help, I could find a way may it be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out need some playing with code like this way, if you know better way I will accept your answer. thanks.

***PS: For using Set in ForEach and unleashing full power of Set, we can use an identifiable type for elements for our Set, then using `id: \.id`, after that we can have multiple elements with same string and deferent id's also the power of Set.***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var set: Set<String> = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        SetforForEachWithBinding(set: $set)
        
    }
}

struct SetforForEachWithBinding: View {
    
    @Binding var set: Set<String>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(set.sorted(by: <), id: \.self) { element in
                
                CustomTextFieldView(string: Binding(
                    get: { return element },
                    set: { newValue in
                        
                        set.remove(element)
                        set.insert(newValue)
                        
                    }
                ))
                
            }
        }
    }
}





struct CustomTextFieldView: View {
    
    @Binding var string: String
    @State private var isUnderEdit: Bool = Bool()
    @State private var isUnderEditString: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter value here...", text: Binding(
            get: {
                
                if isUnderEdit {
                    return isUnderEditString
                }
                else {
                    return string
                }
                
            },
            set: { newValue in
                
                if isUnderEdit {
                    isUnderEditString = newValue
                }
                
            }
        ), onEditingChanged: { value in
            
            if value {
                isUnderEdit = true
                isUnderEditString = string
            }
            else {
                isUnderEdit = false
                string = isUnderEditString
            }
            
        }, onCommit: { })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: sorting the set will result in an array and it might be a very expensive operation depending on the size of your collection. I think you should try using an array, sort it on appear and insert the new element at the correct place instead of sorting all elements again.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I know that when I am using`.sorted(by: <)` it builds an array. Your idea is a great idea. thanks.

Comment: @LeoDabus also expensive. Instead he needs a data structure which is sorted on the fly upon insertions/removal of elements as in a binary search tree.

Comment: @valeCocoa: So you mean set is expensive in general?

Comment: @swiftPunk Nope, I mean sorting the entire collection each time an element gets added or removed to/from it is more expensive, especially since such collection needs to move elements for each sort's swap inside its storage when it comes to arrays or sets based on hash tables.

Comment: @valeCocoa: I do not understand your explaining, and I cannot say which way is cheaper, I mean the way that I used in question/answer or the way Leo says, but I must run some test to see it in action, So you are agree with Leo or disagree?

Comment: @swiftPunk Leo's answer leverages on NSArray's `index(of:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator)` which is the only viable one adopting a Swift array as data structure. It works, but it's not the most efficient compared to adopting a data structure as the one I've suggested to use. That would be based on a self-balancing binary search tree. Such data structure doesn't need to move around its elements when inserting/removing elements to keep the sort. It also works as a set in terms of elements uniqueness and is faster than array for checking if contains an element.

Comment: @valeCocoa: So you can answer my question in the way you think is most faster and best. I used to see and read code to understand better than reading words. Because the topic is much complicated than, that you and me writing in comments.

Comment: @swiftPunk Look I'm gonna put it into an answer but here is not a matter of showing code, but rather of algorithms complexity cohmphernsion therefore choosing the right data structure/algorithm to adopt.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: this answer is merely a synthesis of what we have discussed already in comments. Keep in mind that you'll really be able to see speed improvements with a number of elements *N* that is in the magnitude of thousands or hundreds of thousands. I don't think it suits the case of a simple view, but anyway let's cover it for the sake of the discussion.

Your SwiftUI view: `ForEach(set.sorted(), id: \.self) { … }` has an overall complexity of O(*N* + *N* * Log *N*) where *N* is the count of the elements stored in the collection to sort (from now on let's establish that *N* will always refers to that count value). That is cause sorting the collection has a complexity of O(*N* * Log *N*) and iterating over all its elements (that's what the `ForEach` does) has O(*N*) complexity.

Thus another user has correctly suggested to use a sorted array and keeping it sorted upon addition/removal of elements.
This will effectively reduce the `ForEach` construct to have a O(*N*) complexity, deferring the O(*N*Log*N*) cost to when a mutation of such array is done… But still **after such mutation happens**, the `ForEach` **will be triggered again cause the state of the view has changed: hence you'll still end up with the same complexity cost.** Moreover you'll still have to initially pass a sorted array to the collection, or eventually sort it at initialisation time.

So you could think to improve a bit your original code by using a sorted array, thus leveraging on a `NSArray`'s `index(of:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator)` when mutating it (the `TextField` binding):

```
// assuming elements is the sorted array used to build the ForEach and holding a state in the view
CustomTextFieldView(string: Binding(
                    get: { return element },
                    set: { newValue in
                        elements.remove(element)
                        let i = (elements as NSArray<NSString>)
                            .index(of: newValue, 
                                   inSortedRange: 0..<elements.count, 
                                   options: .insertionIndex, 
                                   usingComparator: { $0.compare($1) }
                        )
                        elements.insert(newValue, at: i)
                    }
                        
                ))
```

Except… **here you're also adding another two O(*N*) complexity factors in order to remove the old element stored in the array and to insert at the right sort position the new element…** Thus your overall complexity for the `ForEach` now will be: O(*3N* + *N* * Log *N*)).
This is worse than using the set as you originally did (`Set` has amortized O(1) complexity for removal/addition of elements thus it can be taken out from the overall complexity cost calculation).

How can you improve instead the overall complexity cost? By choosing a data structure to hold your elements leveraging on *Left Leaning Red-Black Tree*.

This data structure keeps its elements sorted upon mutation, that is the complexity for such operation is almost O(Log *N*).

Thus your whole `ForEach` (including the mutations) should perform in amortized O(*N* + Log *N*).

I've pointed out in the comments an implementation I made of a data structure that leverages on this kind of balanced binary search tree, which is modelled upon an associative array (`Dictionary`), so it's not a `Set` per-se, but you could use it in your case to store your elements as the keys and using `Void` or a `Bool` as the value to associate to them.

Now of course you'll lose the ability to do specific `Set` operations (as  intersections for example), but as you clearly stated in your question you've chosen a `Set` because of its O(1) complexity for membership lookup of an element.
By adopting instead a *left leaning red-black tree* you'll lose that sweet O(1) complexity, trading it for O(Log *N*) on this particular operation, but in the overall complexity of this particular `ForEach` you'll gain a lower cost.

I repeat: in your case I highly doubt the elements count will ever reach a thousands or hundreds of thousands value so to really notice any speed improvement.

Comment: I would like to say there was no useful information for me. But I would like thanks for your time to typing an answer.